# Deleting Jetpack Compose from Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

I'm taking a class on how to use android studio using java language, and i accidentally installed jetpack compose... jetpack compose doesnt let me choose to make a java project, so im trying to delete it...i searched online if there was anything on deleting jetpack compose but theres nothing.....